# How to make a facsimile of corned beef from (plant-based) ground?

Tags: substitutions, vegan, vegetarian, corned-beef, plant-based

I became vegetarian about a year ago, and one thing I still crave constantly is corned beef hash. I've found that impossible meat has been a fairly good substitute for when I really crave a dish with beef in it, and I just cook it like I would have cooked real ground beef - but I'm flummoxed about how to replicated corned beef.

In my (limited) experience, corned beef is made by marinating an entire brisket, then slow cooking it. But of course I only have a vegetarian substitution for ground beef, not for a big slab (as far as I know, no brand of fake meat does pieces that could be marinated). I've never heard of marinating ground beef, and worry that trying to copy this directly wouldn't be a good idea.

Does anyone have any ideas about how to impart corned beef seasonings/spices into a (plant-based) ground beef dish?

Comment: Couldn't you just add salts, spices (pickling spices) that are used in corned beef?

Comment: Do you mean you miss corned beef hash out of a can, or real corned beef hash from leftover brisket and potatoes? They are very different,and would get different answers.

Comment: @GdD I was unaware that a canned version existed, my apologies. I mean the real version (with an understanding that I will never get the brisket texture, but hoping for a similar flavor)

Comment: @bob1 would spices that are intended to pickle (sit in a brine with the meat) work without an extended brining/marinating time?

Comment: If you've never had canned corned beef hash @lilia052 don't start now.

Comment: I was unaware a ‘fresh’ version existed;) Canned corned beef used to be a British staple.

Comment: If anyone can crack the code, it's Mark Thompson of SauceStache.com